# How to make apollo dependant queryes with id loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

i've been trying how to make my query system work but i don't know how.

Im using React D3 Tree, im fetching 4 queryes from Apollo Graphql:

-enterprises
-factories
-areas
-nodes

each one is dependant, for example factories need enterprise id to fetch or areas need factory id.

This is the code i have at the moment

```
// Query Calls
const { data: enterprises } = useQuery(getEnterprises);
const { data: factories } = useQuery(getFactories, {
 variables: {
  "enterprise_id": enterprises?.enterprises[0].id,
},
  skip: !enterprises || !enterprises.enterprises || enterprises.enterprises.length === 0,
});
const { data: areas, } = useQuery(getAreas, {
variables: {
  "factory_id": factories?.factories[0].id,
},
skip: !factories || !factories.factories || factories.factories.length === 0,
});
const { data: nodes, loading: loading2 } = useQuery(getNodes, {
variables: {
  "area_id": areas?.areas[0].id,
},
skip: !areas || !areas.areas || areas.areas.length === 0,
});
```

This aproach works but im only fetching the first of each and i want to fetch all data,
i tried to  use functions that return mapped queries but throws error because the argument is undefined.

Any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are not leveraging graphql given possibilities. This issue would be best fixed on the backend, sou you can query related objects recursively within one query.

```
type Factory {
    id: ID!
    area: Area
    etc...
}

type Area {
    id: ID!
    factory_id: ID
    nodes: [Node]
    etc...
}

type Node{
    id: ID!
    area_id: ID
    etc...
}
```

But maybe a solution to your problem could be to use queries which return a list of objects and you can use an array of ids as variable.
Then you could do something like this:

```
const { data: areas, } = useQuery(getAreas, {
    variables: {
        "factory_ids": factories?.factories?.map(({id})=>id),
    },
    skip: !factories || !factories.factories || factories.factories.length === 0,
});
```